# Is it possible to mount a virtual machine as a networked drive?

Tags: virtualization, mount

I have two virtual machines on two separate networks. They both run Centos 6.

I use the second as a cheap backup for my first VM via FTP. It works fine, but it would simplify things if I could mount second as a network drive.

Is this possible?

Following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-centos-6), the setup on the nfs server seemed to go smoothly. On the client, all went well except when I tried to mount it.

```
 # mount ipaddress:/home/backup /home/backups/
mount.nfs: No such device
```

Adding an entry in fstab

```
ipaddress:/home/backup  /home/backups   nfs      auto,noatime,nolock,bg,nfsvers=3,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

and running `mount -a` gives:

```
mount.nfs: backgrounding "ipaddress:/home/backup"
mount.nfs: mount options: "nolock,bg,nfsvers=3,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800,addr=ipadress"
```

Comment: What virtualisation software do you run? Do both VMs run on the same host? A lot of them come with client tools, which can expose (part of) the filesystem to the host operating system.

Comment: They both use openvz

Comment: OK, that sounds like both VMs are not only on different networks, but also on different hosts. That means that you must communicate over the network anyway; you already have two great answers here, so I won't bother adding a third.

Comment: You can't do this on OpenVZ unless the hosting provider loads the necessary modules for you. Please do yourself a favor and stop using OpenVZ.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, well sort of. You can share the remote server's disk resources.

NFS is a fairly easy way to do this that works well on a LAN and is well supported by CentOS.

- edit the 'remote' server's [/etc/exports](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/exports.5.html) to share the relevant resorces
- edit the local server's [/etc/fstab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) to mount the remote share
- [mount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) the filesystem

job's a goodun

Answer (score 0):

If you're backing up files regularly you could try combining an NFS mount (from the backup VM) with rsnapshot.  I backup a large Ubuntu fileserver this way, with a cron job calling rsnapshot.